# How do I use MPI to send the correct number of derived-type objects?

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90, fortran95, derived-types

Have some experience with MPI, but not with some of the more advanced aspects like derived types, which is what my question is related to.

The code I am working on has several arrays dimensioned `(-1:nx+2,-1:ny+2,-1:nz+2)`.  To make it clear, each process has its own values of `nx`, `ny`, and `nz`.  There is overlap between the arrays.  For instance `x(:,:,-1:2)` on one proc will represent the same information as `x(:,:,nz-1:nz+2)` on the proc just "below" it.

A derived `cell_zface` type has been defined:

```
idir = 3
sizes = (/nx_glb, ny_glb, nz_glb/)   !These nums are the same for all procs.
subsizes = (/nx, ny, 2/)
mpitype = MPI_DATATYPE_NULL
CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY(3, sizes, subsizes, starts, &
    MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, mpireal, mpitype, errcode)
CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(mpitype, errcode)
cell_zface = mpitype
```

Now, this derived type gets used, successfully, in several `MPI_SENDRECV` calls.  For example

```
CALL MPI_SENDRECV( &
        x(-1,-1,   1), 1, cell_zface, proc_z_min, tag, &
        x(-1,-1,nz+1), 1, cell_zface, proc_z_max, tag, &
        comm, status, errcode)
```

As I understand it, this call is sending and receiving two "horizontal" slices (i.e. x-y slices) of the array between procs.

I want to do something a little different, namely sending four "horizontal" slices.  So I try

```
call mpi_send(x(-1,-1,nz-1), 2, cell_zface,    &
                  proc_z_max, rank, comm, mpierr)
```

with an accompanying receive.

And finally, my problem: The code runs, but erroneously.  AFAICT, this sends only two horizontal slices, even though I use "2" instead of "1" as the count argument.  I can fix this by making two calls to `mpi_send`:

```
call mpi_send(x(-1,-1,nz-1), 1, cell_zface,    &
                  proc_z_max, rank, comm, mpierr)
call mpi_send(x(-1,-1,nz+1), 1, cell_zface,    &
                  proc_z_max, rank, comm, mpierr)
```

with accompanying receives, but this is certainly not pretty.

So, why does the `mpi_send` send only two horizontal slices, even though I set the count argument to "2"?  And is there a clean way to do what I want to do here?

Comment: You have to understand that even though you have your own "type", what you truly have underneath it all is one huge contiguous block of memory. So while you can send two `cell_zface` types, the type itself is only as big in memory as the distance between the first and last (in 1D) memory locations used by your type. Aka, the size of your type is not truly `nx*ny*nz`.

Comment: To accomplish what you are looking to do, you would have to give your derived datatype a different extent. Note that the size of the datatype will be the same, but the "extent" (or the amount of memory consecutive versions of this datatype will encompass) will not be. I believe that you can accomplish this with [MPI_Type_create_resized](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Type_create_resized.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every MPI datatype has two sizes, so to speak. One is the true size, i.e. the amount of memory it takes to store all the significant data referred by the datatype. One can think of it as of the amount of space in the actual message that an element of that datatype takes.

Another size is the so-called extent. Each datatype in MPI is a collection of instructions of the type: "go to offset *disp<sub>i</sub>* from the provided buffer location and read/write an element of basic type *type<sub>i</sub>*". The set of all *(type<sub>i</sub>, disp<sub>i</sub>)* pairs is called the type map of the datatype. The minimum offset is called the *lower bound* and the maximum offset + the size of the of the basic type at that offset + any padding needed is called the *upper bound*. The extent of a datatype is the difference between the upper bound and the lower bound and gives the size of the shortest contiguous memory region, which includes all locations accessed by the datatype.

As MPI mandates that no memory location is read from or written to more than once during any communication operation, the pairs in the typemap have to refer to disjoint locations. Therefore, the true extent of a datatype is always bigger than or equal to its size.

MPI uses the extent of the datatype when accessing consecutive elements of that datatype. The following statement:

```
MPI_SEND(buf, n, dtype, ...)
```

results in:

- MPI takes one element of type `dtype` from location `buf` following the rules encoded as the typemape of `dtype`;
- MPI takes the next element starting from location `buf + extent(dtype)`;
- ...
- MPI takes the `n`-th element starting from location `buf + (n-1)*extent(dtype)`.

Primitive datatypes such as `MPI_INTEGER`, `MPI_REAL`, etc. have their extent matching the size of the basic type (`INTEGER`, `REAL`, etc.) + any padding mandated by the architecture, which makes it possible to send arrays of the basic type by simply specifying the count of elements.

Now, back to your case. You are creating a datatype that covers an `nx x ny x 2` subarray from an `nx_glb x ny_glb x nz_glb` array. The size of that datatype is indeed `nx * ny * 2` times the size of `mpireal`, but the extent is actually `nx_glb * ny_glb * nz_glb` times the extent of `mpireal`. In other words:

```
MPI_SEND(buf, 2, cell_zface, ...)
```

will not extract two consecutive `nx x ny x 2` slabs from the big array at `buf`. Rather, it will extract one slab from each of two consecutive arrays of size `nx_glb x ny_glb x nz_glb`, starting from location *(start<sub>x</sub>, start<sub>y</sub>, start<sub>z</sub>)* in each array. If your program doesn't segfault when run, consider yourself lucky.

Now comes the tricky part. MPI allows one to give each datatype a fake extent (that's why I called the extent as defined earlier "true") by artificially setting the value of the lower and the upper bounds. Doing so does not affect the size of the datatype or its typemap (i.e. MPI still goes to the same offsets and manipulates elements of the same basic types), but affects the strides in memory that MPI makes while accessing consecutive elements of the given datatype. Earlier, setting the extent was done by "sandwiching" the datatype in a stricture between elements of the special pseudotypes `MPI_LB` and `MPI_UB`. Ever since MPI-2, the `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_RESIZED` is used to achieve the same.

```
integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: lb, extent
integer :: newtype

! First obtain the extent of the old type used to construct cell_zface
call MPI_TYPE_GET_EXTENT(mpireal, lb, extent, errcode)
! Adjust the extent of cell_zface
extent = (nx_glb * ny_glb * subsizes(3)) * extent
call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_RESIZED(cell_zface, lb, extent, newtype, errcode)
call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(newtype, errcode)
! Get rid of the previous type
call MPI_TYPE_FREE(cell_zface, errcode)
cell_zface = newtype
```

You can now use `cell_zface` to send several consecutive slabs.

An alternative and presumably simpler approach is to set the size of 3-rd dimension of the array equal to the size of the 3-rd dimension of the subarray while calling `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY`:

```
idir = 3
subsizes = (/nx, ny, 2/)
sizes = (/nx_glb, ny_glb, subsizes(3)/)   !These nums are the same for all procs.
mpitype = MPI_DATATYPE_NULL
CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY(3, sizes, subsizes, starts, &
    MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, mpireal, mpitype, errcode)
CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(mpitype, errcode)
cell_zface = mpitype
```

In both cases I assume that `starts(3)` is equal to `0`.

Comment: Didn't expect so much work to go into an answer!  Thank you very much for a complete and very helpful answer.  You're the man!

Comment: So, if I understand it right, the stride of this data type is pretty much the size of the entire 3D array.  Here's a question that I know you can't answer definitively, but would appreciate whatever insight you have:  You've probably figured out that I didn't write this code.  So, does it make sense having a stride equal to the size of the whole array?  I can't think of any application where that would be useful.  Having a stride equal to one dimension, or the product of two dimensions, sure.  But the whole array?  Thanks.

Comment: The subarray datatype constructor's primary intent is for use in MPI-IO. Different MPI ranks provide the same array dimensions and specify different sections within it, which gives them (parallel) access to the array data stored as a single binary file. The extent of such datatype is intentionally equal to the size of the whole array - it allows one to easily read from a collection of such arrays stored consecutively. The subarray constructor can also be used for datatypes that represent halo regions in domain decomposition, but one has to be careful and keep in mind its origin.

Comment: Whether that stride makes sense for your code, it depends on how the datatype is used. For the example given in the question, the answer is definitely no; it makes more sense to have a datatype whose extent equals the amount of memory two XY-planes of the big array take.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537451/writing-distributed-arrays-using-mpi-io-and-cartesian-topology) for a good example of the intended use of `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY` (although in C).